# Property 'x' does not exist on type when using optional chaining operator

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like to use optional chaining operator in typescript, but I get the error `Property 'dog' does not exist on type '{ name: string; cat: Record<string, string>; }'.`
. Totally make sense the error complain from typescript but I am wondering if anyway for me to walk around?
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwG4FMxQK4CcVYFwwDeYcAtigdFgJZgDmA3MHFHgEoqhYIA8VtdADQx+9AHwBfGAF4iAWABQMGCXIEA5AEEANtWAp1gxcuat5S5SrIUY6gCK04AC3XGYExRIaLFoSLAQQOgA5axl4ZDRMHCwAfgA6QMZfcAgQbRR47SCACiTQ8gBKbwUgA)

```
const adventurer: {name: string;cat:Record<string, string>} = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};

const dogName = adventurer?.dog;
console.log(dogName);
```

Comment: The way around it is to either change the type or bypass the compiler (e.g., via type assertion). The optional chaining has no relevance to either of these.

Comment: Right, optional chaining does not work this way, see [microsoft/TypeScript#33736](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33736); there's no built-in construct that acts like a type guard adding a property to a type not known to have it (like [microsoft/TypeScript#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732)) so you need to do something yourself (like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBP9kW)) if you really care.

Comment: Related: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-type#:~:text=The%20%22Property%20does%20not%20exist,type%20with%20variable%20key%20names.

Comment: wow lots of stuff on google: https://www.google.com/search?q=property+does+not+exist+on+type

Answer (score 5):

### Why does this happen?

You are telling the TS compiler by providing a type for adventurer, that `adventurer` will **never** have a property `dog` (EDIT: thanks @jcalz for pointing out that's not *exactly* true. Have a look at the comment below for more info). There are two main ways around this:

### Tell TypeScript you know better by asserting another type (like any)

```
const dogName = (adventurer as any)?.dog;
console.log(dogName);
```

### Change the type of adventurer to optionally include `dog`

```
const adventurer: {name: string;cat:Record<string, string>; dog?: string} = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};

const dogName = adventurer?.dog;
console.log(dogName);
```

Comment: "`adventurer` will **never** have a property `dog`"... this isn't exactly true because TypeScript has [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing), see [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAV9QW).  There are [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) which make it less likely to accidentally annotate an object literal this way directly, but it's more of a linter rule than a type system constraint.